# Angular Datatable >> How to get total number of rows and sum of the all amount values

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, datatables, angular-datatables

Angular Datatable >> How to get total number of rows and sum of the all amount values. Need to get the total number of rows of the table. I tried with below table and getting only first page records. Please suggest me how to `get total number of records across all page`s and need to get the `sum of the total records values`. I tried with below code,

```
getTotalAmount(){
   let amountValues="";
    let rowCount = $("table > tbody").children().length;
    console.log("rowCount ::: " + rowCount);
    for(var i=0;i<rowCount;i++){
      if(this.persons[i].firstName === 'Superman' && this.persons[i].index != '')
        console.log(this.persons[i].index);
        amountValues += parseFloat(this.persons[i].enteredDebit);
    }
    console.log("amountValues >>>>>>>" + amountValues);
  }
```

[Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datatables-gitter-535u18?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: `this.personas.length` contains all the possible rows of your table, since you are cycling this array in the html. For The values, what do you mean? The json you fetch returns a dataset of Id, Name and LastName.

Comment: Actually my issue is, im able to access only display page records, im not able to access across all pages.

Comment: I'm trying to get all sum of amount values (Across all pages) of firstName of "superman"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the updated code. You have to use persons[i].id instead of index.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datatables-gitter-zbcrwx?file=app/app.component.ts